# Convert blob to pdf file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

Using react-pdf's BlobProvider, I'm trying to store the file to state. Here's what I tried:

```
 MyDocument = () => {
        return (
            <Document>
                <Page size="A4" style={stylez.page}>
                    <View style={stylez.section}>
                        <Text>Section TesterYo</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={stylez.section}>
                        <Text>Section #2</Text>
                    </View>
                </Page>
            </Document>
        )
    }

 LoadPdf = () => {
        let myPdf = <BlobProvider document={this.MyDocument}/>
        var file = new File([myPdf], 'filename.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf', lastModified:Date.now()});


        this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, file] }, () => console.log(this.state))
 }
```

When downloaded this provides a damaged pdf.

Comment: I would recommend you to use this plugin `file-saver` instead.

Comment: ```const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });  saveAs(blob, 'filename');```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The file comes from where exactly; database as a blob ? When you 'download' the pdf; do you mean download to your local machine or are you implying you're loading in javascript and display in HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the blob data into a file and place it in `this.state.files` The file should come as a blob, I'm downloading to the local machine yes.

Comment: @buzz And the what are you doing afterwards with the file inside state? It might be easy putting the blob inside state instead depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's being posted to an endpoint for upload to the server, along with some user selected files.

Comment: @buzz You're not getting the blob back correctly, use `const blob = pdf(MyDoc).toBlob();` on the myPdf line. And place the blob inside the file constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the blob back correctly like so in the [documentation](https://react-pdf.org/advanced)

```js
import { BlobProvider, Document, Page } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const MyDoc = (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      // My document data
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <BlobProvider document={MyDoc}>
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => {
        // Do whatever you need with blob here
        return <div>There's something going on on the fly</div>
      }}
    </BlobProvider>
  </div>
);
```

or

```js
import { pdf, Document, Page } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const MyDoc = (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      // My document data
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

const blob = pdf(MyDoc).toBlob();
```

Comment: I've tried both as per the documentation - 1) adds the function  2) throws: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined'