# How to download a file from the API in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to download a file that comes from the api in React.js
Thank you very much in advance...

This is my code

-- Consult the api --

```js
const[data, setData]= useState(null);
const downloadRelase = async (id) => {
  try {
    const result = await clientAxios.get(`/api/comunicados/download/${id}/0`);
    setData(result.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

-- Response "data" --

[image: image the data]

-- JSX --

```html
<div className="p-0 col-12 col-md-6 text-primary">
  <a className="w-auto p-0 btn" href={} onClick={()=> downloadRelase(relase.id)}>
    Descargar firmado 
  </a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a className="w-auto p-0 btn" href="#!">
    Verificar firma
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You are downloading it correctly but you have to handle it properly. You can use frontend pdf libraries

Comment: Hello @ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV What I want is for the pdf file to be downloaded when I click and that it can be seen. I was investigating and I think that "URL.createObjectURL (new Blob ([data])" should be used but I can't fully understand what would follow next

Comment: Read: [https://react-pdf.org/advanced] and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575805/convert-blob-to-pdf-file]